# How to set the yellow phase only for specific lanes in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic, traffic-simulation

In AnyLogic intersection with traffic lights, I have multiple cases where the green (or red) light on the specific lane x direction (lane connector) stays the same color over multiple phases.

Between these phases, it makes no sense to put a yellow light on these lane connectors. Is there a way I can make the yellow light only for specific connectors?

If somebody is willing to provide a code, I can put a specific example for a 3-way intersection, where C1-C6 are the identifiers of lane connectors:

Phase 1: 1234 green

Phase 2: 126 green

Phase 3: 356 green